# Не работают библиотеки javaFx в android studio

Tags: android-studio, javafx, intellij-idea, gradle

Пытаюсь прицепить плагин javaFx, через gradle. (openjfx).
Библиотеки вроде скачиваются (находятся в списке), но использовать их в классах не получается.
Как решить данную проблему? Прилагаю скрины.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-rc01'
        classpath 'org.openjfx:javafx-plugin:0.0.9'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin'
apply plugin: 'application'

javafx {
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
    version '11.0.2'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()}}
```

[image: Ошибка импортирования]

[image: Ошибки в gradle сборке]

Код с https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin
мне не помог
Прошу строго не материться, новичок в java.

Comment: Просто для общего развития интересно - зачем Вам javafx в android studio?

Comment: Решил попробовать сделать интерфейс на javaFx. Изначально сделал на десктопы, теперь хочу на андроид перевести уже сделанный проект